# C++ overloaded method binding with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, overloading, virtual-inheritance, method-signature

Ok so I have a question relating to the output of the following code (which is 111222223)

```
#include <iostream>
struct C {
 virtual int eq(const C& other) const { return 1; }
};
struct SC : C {
 virtual int eq(const C& other) const { return 2; } 
 virtual int eq(const SC& other) const { return 3; }
};
void go(const C& c, const C& c1, const SC& sc) {
 using namespace std;

 cout << c.eq(c) << endl;
 cout << c.eq(c1) << endl;
 cout << c.eq(sc) << endl;

 cout << c1.eq(c) << endl;
 cout << c1.eq(c1) << endl;
 cout << c1.eq(sc) << endl;

 cout << sc.eq(c) << endl;
 cout << sc.eq(c1) << endl;
 cout << sc.eq(sc) << endl;
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) { 
 go(C(), SC(), SC());
 return 0;
}
```

So I understand that I am using the dot operator with a reference that will dynamically bind the proper virtual method based on the run-time type of the caller (would need -> with pointers but OK for dynamic minding here). What I don't understand is  why the second to last cout line prints '2' and not '3'. Is this because the method signature is static, so the method is selected based on the static signature in the proper derived type SC? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ there is no support for multiple dispatch, only for the object on which the function is called (dynamic dispatch only applies to the `this` pointer). In the expression:

```
sc.eq(c1);
```

the compiler will dispatch to the dynamic type of `sc`, but will use the static type of `c1`

Answer (score 2):

This is due to function resolution rules.

In this call:

```
sc.eq(c1);
```

Only one function is elegible to be called, once c1 is of type `struct C` with `eq` dynamicly overloaded.

But in the call

```
sc.eq(sc);
```

you have two possible `eq` functions to be called. The first one is declared in `struct C` with the dynamicly overloaded `eq` and the second is the one declared in `struct SC`. Once `sc` is of type `struct SC` the last method is more viable than the former.

That why you are getting `3` as result.

Comment: @ThomasBadan How do you explain that c1.eq(sc); returns 2? c1 is an instance of `struct SC`, and the argument `sc` is of type `struct SC`, so it should return 3, shouldn't it?

Comment: @IgorPopov Only sc is of type `struct SC`. c1 is of type `struct C` (look at the definition of go function, even if the original object is of SC), so it only knows about the dynamic overload `eq`. i.e., `virtual int eq(const C& other) const { return 2; }`.

Comment: @ThomasBadan +1, now I got a better understanding of subclassing and binding :)

Comment: @ThomasBadan One last question from me: How in `c.eq(sc)` object `c` of type `struct C` knows about `sc`? There is no declaration of `eq` for argument of this type in type `struct C`.

Comment: @IgorPopov sc is of type `struct C` too. Look at its declaration. It is an descendent of `struct C` (inheritance). So, any function that expect `struct C` can be used to pass object declared as its descendents (in this case, sc). So, in the case of `sc.eq(sc)`, there is two elegible functions to be called. The first one has as parameter `struct C`, which sc is a kind of. The second has as paramenter `struct SC`, which sc is a kind of too. The overload resolution rules says that the second is more viable than the former.